# Validating inputs representing Resources and Sub-resources in REST

Tags: web-services, api, validation, rest

I have a resource called user and a sub-resource called images. To access a particular image, the only way to do it is using the URL: /users/{userId}/images/{imageId}.

The database schema is such that one user can have multiple images.

The client sends us inputs for "{userId}" and "{imageId}". I would have to validate these inputs. My question is pertaining to validating the "{imageId}" input. I have two options here:

Option 1: Validate if a particular imageId belongs to that userId. If I see no images for the given userId, then throw an error that "There is no image for the given userId".

Option 2: Validate if the image with the given "{imageId}" exists. Throw an error saying "Image with given imageId does not exist". Then again validate (another DB check) if the given "{imageId}", belongs to that "{userId}".

Of the two options above, which option is the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a resource called user and a sub-resource called images. To
>   access a particular image, the only way to do it is using the URL:
>   /users/{userId}/images/{imageId}. The database schema is such that one
>   user can have multiple images.

I think you misunderstood the URI structure restrictions of REST:

## There are no restrictions about how to build URIs.

You can use your own conventions, it does not matter, because the clients are decoupled from the URI structures... For example I can say that my images are under the `/images/{imageId}`. It is perfectly valid...

You don't have to map resources to entities, and by complex applications you won't be able to do that.

> Of the two options above, which option is the right approach?

You can send back 404 with a message, that there is no resource under the URI. Error messages about the URI structure does not mean anything to the client. URIs are opaque to the client.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I understand that I can represent an image as "/images/{imageId}". I specifically wanted to highlight the fact that for some reason the client cannot access an image unless the url is: "/users/userId/images/imageId" and this cannot be changed as this is the way it is configured already. Based on your response, I think you are asking me to take option 1. Thanks